# VssClientCredentials with accesstoken credentials in VSTS authentication

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am reading licensing information of user from VSTS but it is not authenticating itself with Access Token credentials.

How do you authenticate with an access token?

```cs
string accessToken = $"{AccessTokenHere}";
VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential accessTokenCredentials = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(new VssOAuthAccessToken(accessToken));
var credentials = new VssClientCredentials(accessTokenCredentials);

VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(this.ServerUri), credentials);
var licensingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<LicensingHttpClient>();
var accountEntitlement = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync().Result;
var license = accountEntitlement.License;
```

Comment: Do you want to use PAT or OAuth token? What error did you get?

Comment: I don't have PAT I am generating token through VSS client SDK. using this method of sdk: "VSS.getAccessToken()"

Comment: Alsmaili's response is the answer (I've tested it), it should be marked as such

Answer (score 5):

I think, you can skip the following line, when you have the bearer token from an oauth2 authentication:

```
// skip this line in your code: var credentials = new VssClientCredentials(accessTokenCredentials);
```

For me, this code is working:

```
VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential credentials = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(AccessToken);
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/[your org]"), credentials);
var client = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var projects = client.GetProjects().Result;
```

Please also make sure, you register the correct scopes in your application for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
        String collectionUri = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com";
        VssBasicCredential creds = new VssBasicCredential("", personalaccesstoken);
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
        var licensingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<LicensingHttpClient>();
        var accountEntitlement = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync().Result;
        var license = accountEntitlement.License;
```

About personal access token, you can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: I am getting this error with this code: TF400813: The user '5187a2fa-e019-4228-93b3-f0b93d7e693f' is not authorized to access this resource.

Comment: I don't have PAT I am generating token through VSS client SDK. using this this method of sdk: "VSS.getAccessToken()"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using a Personal Access Token.

```
VssBasicToken token = new VssBasicToken(new NetworkCredential("", "string-token"));

VssCredentials credentials = new VssBasicCredential(token);

VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(connectionUri, credentials);
```