# Unable to get TFS User Entitlements in Azure Devops Service

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I have added scope **vso.entitlements** in VSTS extension which was working perfectly but now when I run extension with same scopes in Azure Devops service it is giving me an error.

**VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com.**

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/accountname"), new VssBasicCredential("", oAuthAccessToken));
            LicensingHttpClient licensingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<LicensingHttpClient>();
            AccountEntitlement accountEntitlement = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync().Result;
            License license = accountEntitlement.License;
```

Comment: Based on the error message, it should be the permission issue. How did you get the access token? Is the Access tokens expired? What about using PAT? Reference this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966279/vssclientcredentials-with-accesstoken-credentials-in-vsts-authentication?rq=1

Comment: It is oAuth token generated by client api VSSDK. Authentication of application is running on oAuth which is working perfectly on VSTS and it is giving license information of user but creating problem with Azure Devops Service. Please confirm if it is not supported on Azure Service.

Comment: I don't have PAT I am generating token through VSS client SDK. using this method of sdk: "VSS.getAccessToken()"

Comment: What about also adding the scope `vso.memberentitlementmanagement`?